# Is there already (in JDK) a method for getting a value by index in array (plus default)?

Tags: java

I wrote this utility method:

```
public class ArrayUtils {
    public static <T> T get(T[] array, int index, T def) {
        return index < array.length ? array[index] : def;
    }
}
```

Is this method already part of the JDK ?

or in a third-party library (guava, commons-lang3...). I don't want to include a library only for this method.

Comment: The question isn't very clear.

Comment: writing the comparison that way around is non-intuitive - it would be more usual to write `return index < array.length ? ...`

Comment: **Side note:** I would highly discourage to include a whole third-party library just for one method

Comment: That is already very shorter.

Comment: What kind of `short` you mean? This is already short.

Comment: I don't quite see what people are downvoting. It looks like you have a valid question followed by a separate, also possibly valid question, but the presentation isn't very clear, and the second question could be solved with a quick google search. Maybe post this on Code Review?

Comment: I don't think that returning default value for `element out of bounds` is a good idea. It prevents the application from detecting this important exception(al) condition.

Comment: @BackSlash indeed. I don't want to include one of these libraries only for this method. I have several projects some depends on guava others on commons-lang3. I am looking for this method.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ my question was really unclear. I just edit it.

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix my question was really unclear. I just edit it.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera right. My question was really unclear. I just edit it.

Comment: @GermannArlington i was using this method for an optional parameter in  the `main method args`.

Comment: If that is the case I assume that you will have a separate array of default values corresponding to each optional parameter in which case you should just copy the optional parameters array starting from the first omitted parameter to the end of passed parameters array... And you will not need your method at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search to confirm this, and there is nothing similar to that function.

I saw in the comment section you mentioned this is for optional arguments. In that case rather than trying to retrieve a parameter by index forcibly, you should set default values, loop through the arguments, *then* set the values.

It can be as simple as a switch statement (JDK7+) or a complex parser, but the key is this approach affords your user more flexibility in giving parameters, and it makes for more maintainable code.